# intellij Mac set a SDK home path to /usr

Tags: intellij-idea, sdk, path, erlang

Using `Intellij IDEA 14.1.2` I am trying to set an **Erlang SDK home path**, the only option I have for doing this is a file browser that does not let me view my `/usr/local` file. That is, I have **no** option for typing the desired path. I am forced to use the Apple gui file browser (that does not show `/bin` or `/usr`)

`File -> Project Structure -> SDK's`

I made a sym-link, but I don't really want stray links.

`ln -s /usr/local/path/to/erlang ~/erlang`

I can "type" the classpath and sourcepath but not the main "Erlang SDK home path:"

any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution: installing erlang in a directory visible for Intellij IDEA

Steps: 
// 1-7 could be found here http://www.erlang.org/doc/installation_guide/INSTALL.html 
1. Download "OTP 17.5 Source File" from http://www.erlang.org/download.html
2. $ tar -zxf otp_src_17.5.tar.gz (unpack)
3. $ cd otp_src_17.5
4. $ export ERL_TOP='pwd'
5. $ ./configure --prefix=/users/myuser/otp (use obsolete path; "~/" didn't work for me)
6. $ make
7. $ sudo make install
// 
8. File -> Project Structure -> SDK's (chose /users/myuser/otp)
9. Finally to be able to use erlang from command line still; edit or create .bash_profile in the home directory and add the erlang's directory to the PATH variable (export PATH=${PATH}:/users/myuser/otp/bin/)
10. Finally Finally :) $ source .bash_profile

For me that did the job!

Answer (score 12):

I found a [similar solution](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/118187/67587) on AskDifferent posted by [bmike](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/5472/bmike):

Pressing <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>g</kbd> will open a dialog where you can type the path of any folder that you want to open.

Or, you can press <kbd>shift</kbd> + <kbd>command</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> to see hidden files and then navigate to `/usr/local/path/to/erlang`.

Answer (score 0):

I also didn't want "stray links". Nevertheless, I have tried it and it didn't even work.
Do you think it's possible to change it from some config file ~/Library/Preferences/IntelliJIdea14
I tried to add to (project.default.xml) something like  with no success.

Comment: tbh it's probably easier just using emacs, there is a nice mode for erlang

Comment: can I install erlang on a different location ~/ for example ?

Comment: As far as I am aware you can. Did you try making a sym-link? that should work fine

Comment: I have tried sym-link, you browse the directory but when choosing it I got (The selected directory is not a valid home for Erlang SDK)